# Conflict between my two addons due to bpy.types.Scene

Tags: python, scripting

Running one addon would disable the directories, string inputs and float sliders of my other addon

I eventually found out the block of code responsible.

Both of my add-ons have this block of code to register the directories, strings, and float (bpy.types.PropertyGroup)

Addon 1:

```
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type= MyProperties)
        
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
```

Addon 2

```
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
    bpy.types.Scene.example_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type= MyProperties_Node_titles)
        
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

    del bpy.types.Scene.example_props
```

However, running one code will disable the directories, strings and float sliders of the other addon.

Before running the other code:

[image]

After running the other code:

[image]

Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: 1st off `bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type= MyProperties)` and `del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool` should be outdented so they line up under the for statement and are only called once during resgister/unregister instead of the loop. next off `bpy.types.Scene.my_tool` change my_tool to be specific for each addon like addon_name_props.

Comment: I did outdent the text you said, and I also changed bpy.types.Scene.my_tool to bpy.types.Scene.example_props . But it still doesnt work, should I do that to both addons?

Comment: the variable for your property group pointer should be unique for each addon. also assuming you made the change in the addon's installation file (for windows something like (C:\Users\nezum\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6) you will need to reload scripts (blender icon > system > reload scripts) then enable the addon

Comment: Hello, please post the relevant part of the other addon (props registration)

Comment: I added it in the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to change

```
mytool = scene.my_tool
```

in my classes, once I changed that. Everything got fixed.